# Large Samech in Bemidbar 13:30

Tags: mesorah-tradition, parashat-shelach

A mesorah records that the samekh in Bemidbar 13:30 ויהס כלב is large (see marginal note in Artscroll and elsewhere). Yet none of the printed editions which I have consulted actually conform to this tradition. Have you come across any info on this?

Comment: There are indeed lots of different traditions of various letters that are rarely implemented today. I'm not sure if that's all you're looking for. what other "info on this" do you seek?

Comment: This edition has it https://books.google.co.il/books?id=M31Rh6p0AoEC&pg=RA1-PA204&lpg=RA1-PA204&dq=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A1+%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91+%22%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%9A+%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%22&source=bl&ots=5PNwg2sNJB&sig=ACfU3U0kU9E91y9cWDUG1nm0lv_yAnrMCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSg_q9y5TjAhWMJFAKHfcZCNYQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%D7%A1%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91%20%22%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%9A%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%22&f=false

Comment: @DoubleAA is correct in that there is no agreement on all the large and small letters. My shul has 6 usable *Sifrei Torah*. One of the most common readings throughout the year includes the *13 middot* (I estimate we read that verse about 15 times per year.) In some Sifrei Torah the Nun of *notzer* is big, and in others, not. I think one Torah has no large letters anywhere, though, that's unusual. Not having the large or small letters does not make the Torah pasul (unusable.)

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough in [Torah Shleimah Vol 29](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/51444) which discusses the unsual letters in the Torah - ָכתַב התורה ואוֹתִיוֹתֶיה -  I can't seem to find a reference to this enlarged **ס** in either of the lists nor with a (possibly unreliable) text search.

Also in [Volume 39 - שלח](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/51469) there is no mention of the enlarged ס [on this verse](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51469&st=&pgnum=39&hilite=) - meaning it is (probably) not mentioned in any Midrashim

The Keter site doesn't have anything about the ס either [on this verse.](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/4/13/30)

And The [Minchas Shay says](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.13.30?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Minchat_Shai_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.13.30&lang2=he) that in reliable texts it is not large, though he mentions 2 sources that seem to have it enlarged.

> **ויהס**. בספרים מדויקים כ"י **אין הסמ"ך רבתי** גם במסרה גדולה ליתי. ואיתא בדוכתא סמ"ך סוף ספר קהלת ‏
> אכן בנוסח אחר כ"י מאלפ"א בית"א רבתי איתא וכן בתיקון ס"ת ישן. ‏

[This list](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/natlang/hebrew/hebrew_bible.html) does include it with 5 references mentioned.

Comment: Those lists in Torah Shlema don't discuss big and small letters if I remember correctly. They also don't mention the Yud in יגדל נא כח ה for instance, or the Ayin Dalet in Shema. I suggest removing them from this post since its misleading information

Comment: @DoubleAA - my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question is that there is no agreement as to whether the samech should be large. I thought it was universally agree eg the ayin and dalet in the first paragraph of shema. –